# JSON Response for Visual Studio 2010 project

Tags: .net, json.net

I have a JSON Response from an HTTP request and I'm unable to put together the last peice of the puzzle... I've worked out 90% of what I need to do but now I'm stuck and cannot find any clues elsewhere.

Below is the response I get:

```
{
  "adult": false,
  "backdrop_path": "/mOTtuakUTb1qY6jG6lzMfjdhLwc.jpg",
  "belongs_to_collection": {
    "backdrop_path": "/mOTtuakUTb1qY6jG6lzMfjdhLwc.jpg",
    "id": 10,
    "name": "Star Wars Collection",
    "poster_path": "/6rddZZpxMQkGlpQYVVxb2LdQRI3.jpg"
  },
  "budget": 11000000,
  "genres": [
    {
      "id": 28,
      "name": "Action"
    },
    {
      "id": 14,
      "name": "Fantasy"
    },
    {
      "id": 878,
      "name": "Science Fiction"
    }
  ],
  "homepage": "http://www.starwars.com",
  "id": 11,
  "imdb_id": "tt0076759",
  "original_title": "Star Wars: Episode IV: A New Hope",
  "overview": "Princess Leia is captured.",
  "popularity": 84.8,
  "poster_path": "/qoETrQ73Jbd2LDN8EUfNgUerhzG.jpg",
  "production_companies": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Lucasfilm"
    },
    {
      "id": 8265,
      "name": "Paramount"
    }
  ],
  "production_countries": [
    {
      "iso_3166_1": "TN",
      "name": "Tunisia"
    },
    {
      "iso_3166_1": "US",
      "name": "United States of America"
    }
  ],
  "release_date": "1977-12-27",
  "revenue": 775398007,
  "runtime": 121,
  "spoken_languages": [
    {
      "iso_639_1": "en",
      "name": "English"
    }
  ],
  "tagline": "A long time ago in a galaxy far, far away...",
  "title": "Star Wars: Episode IV: A New Hope",
  "vote_average": 8.8,
  "vote_count": 75
}
```

Using Newtonsoft Json I'm able to get everything I need except the "belongs_to_collection" part... my code so far goes like:

```
    Dim jsonResults As JObject = JObject.Parse(searchResults)
    Dim genreItems As JArray = DirectCast(jsonResults("genres"), JArray)
    Dim productionCompaniesItems As JArray = DirectCast(jsonResults("production_companies"), JArray)


    Dim release_Date As String = CStr(jsonResults.SelectToken("release_date"))
    Dim overview As String = CStr(jsonResults.SelectToken("overview"))
    Dim homepage As String = CStr(jsonResults.SelectToken("homepage"))
    Dim tagline As String = CStr(jsonResults.SelectToken("tagline"))
    Dim imdb_id As String = CStr(jsonResults.SelectToken("imdb_id"))

    Dim vote_Average As String = CStr(jsonResults.SelectToken("vote_average").ToString)
    Dim popularity As String = CStr(jsonResults.SelectToken("popularity").ToString)
    Dim vote_Count As String = CStr(jsonResults.SelectToken("vote_count").ToString)
    Dim revenue As String = CStr(jsonResults.SelectToken("revenue").ToString)
    Dim runtime As String = CStr(jsonResults.SelectToken("runtime").ToString)
    Dim budget As String = CStr(jsonResults.SelectToken("budget").ToString)
    Dim adult As Boolean = CBool(jsonResults.SelectToken("adult"))

        Dim item As JObject
        Dim jtoken As JToken

        'Genre List

        For i As Integer = 0 To genreItems.Count - 1

            item = DirectCast(genreItems(i), JObject)
            jtoken = item.First

            While jtoken IsNot Nothing

                Dim jProperty = DirectCast(jtoken, JProperty).Name.ToString()

                If jProperty = "name" Then
                    'Debug.Print("Genres: " & DirectCast(jtoken, JProperty).Value.ToString())
                End If

                jtoken = jtoken.[Next]

            End While

        Next
```

Anyone able to point me in the right direction so I can get the last peice finished?

Thanks

**Edit**

```
    Dim collection As JObject = DirectCast(jsonResults("belongs_to_collection"), JObject)
    Dim id As String = CStr(collection.SelectToken("id").ToString)
```

That does actually work when "belongs_to_collection" contains data but it errors out when it doesn't with the error:

```
Unable to cast object of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JValue' to type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject'
```

How can I test to see if it contains data before I try and get anything from it?

**Edit 2**
Ok, so its sorted now... pretty sure I tried this before and it didn't work but it seems to be working now. The solution is:

```
        Dim test_Collection As String = CStr(jsonResults.SelectToken("belongs_to_collection").ToString)

    If test_Collection = "" Then
        Console.WriteLine("--- NOTHING ---")
    Else
        Dim collection As JObject = DirectCast(jsonResults("belongs_to_collection"), JObject)
        Dim id As String = CStr(collection.SelectToken("id").ToString)
        Console.WriteLine(id)
    End If
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Does this work?

```
Dim collection As JObject = DirectCast(jsonResults("belongs_to_collection"), JObject)
```

Then get the rest of it from the collection JObject the same as you are doing to your top level JObject?

Comment: I tried that before but tried again just to make sure... it doesn't work. It returns the error: Unable to cast object of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JValue' to type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject'

Comment: I should also say that "belongs_to_collection" doesn't always contain a value. Because of this I tried measuring the result for null, "", DbNull.value etc but was also unsuccessful in doing that.

Comment: Ok, so its sorted now... pretty sure I tried this before and it didn't work but it seems to be working now. The solution is in the main post.

Answer (score 0):

If you are comfortable with C#, then you might want to take a peek at [wattmdb](http://wattmdb.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/15940#305222) library.
This is the TMDB API wrapper library, which is doing the same thing as you are.